# I try to save an image with ajax and laravel but arrives null

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm tring to upload a image to the database and obtain its id, but i don't understand why; when I try to get the image in laravel it return null. In the image variable in jquery this have the object image.

This is my ajax code:

```
var imagesPreview = function(input, placeToInsertImagePreview) {

    if (input.files) {
        var files = input.files;
        var filesAmount = input.files.length;
        var url = $("#form-step").attr('action');



        for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) { 
            var image = files[i];
             var reader = new FileReader();
             var src_imagenagregada;
             formData= new FormData();
             formData.append("image", image);
                $.ajax({
                url: url,
                headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'},
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(data){
                    alert('success');
                }
                 });
            }
```

This is my controller in laravel:

```
public function save23($keyCanvas , $stepNumber, $stepType, \Illuminate\Http\Request $request){

   $file = $request->file('image');
}
```

Comment: Try adding this header: `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'`.

Comment: Share how you are calling `imagesPreview` ?

Comment: show a `dd()` of `$request->all()`